# Multiple Greengrass Core devices in a group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot-greengrass

What I am trying to achieve is having a group of multiple core devices, where the lambda functions gets executed, and these devices will have to send and receive messages across them.

These are my questions regarding it:

1. Can I have a group with only core devices?
2. In the above mentioned case, the same lambda functions will be running on all the cores, so in this case, how to create the subscriptions as the target and source will be the lambda functions?

Please advise me.

Answer (score 3):

Greengrass Group only supports one Greengrass core.
But you can have multiple Greengrass Aware Devices in the same group and have them connect to the same Greengrass Core.
See details in [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/device-group.html).